# convert everything import from sqlQuery to character

Tags: excel, r, rodbc

I have an xls file to be imported into R using RODBC, one of the column has the following data:

```
1,1A,2,3,4
```

When I use the `sqlQuery` command, this column is converted into number and gives the following:

```
1,NA,2,3,4
```

How can I stop `sqlQuery` from converting this column? I have tried `as.is=TRUE`, but seems not working.

To make the question more general, I need everything to be imported text (i.e. do not try to do any conversion for me), is it possible in `sqlQuery`?

Comment: I would easier to help if we could reproduce your problem. (I can't reproduce this behavior on my machine, for example.)